# Bind to grid row height inside datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

If I have a `ListBox` in WPF that has a `Grid` inside it's `DataTemplate`, how would I reference that `Grid`'s various `ColumnDefinition` properly?

What I am trying to do is have a `ListBox` that contain grids with 3 columns each. The last 2 columns have circles that can be red or green. In order to draw the circle, I am using `Ellipse`, and in order to make that into a circle, I simply want to bind the width of the ellipse to the height of the `Row` for that `Grid`.

Since there is only 1 row in each `Grid` in the `ListBox`, this should result in the `Ellipse` staying as a circle no matter how I size the `ListBox` or `Grid`.

I am having trouble however, properly referencing that `RowDefinition` from inside of the `Grid`, which is itself inside the `DataTemplate`. What I have currently is the following:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TermServListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TermServs}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <converter:ValidPathToBgColor x:Key="ValPthToBgClr"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="MainTermServListGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TServer}"/>
                <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainTermServListGrid, Path=RowDefinitions/ActualHeight}" Fill="{Binding IsOldPathValid, Converter={StaticResource ValPthToBgClr}}"/>
                <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainTermServListGrid, Path=RowDefinitions/Height}" Fill="{Binding IsNewPathValid, Converter={StaticResource ValPthToBgClr}}"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This results in each ellipse being a large ellipse (oval) shape instead of a circle that I want which I think is due to improper binding on my part. Is there another way to bind to a property that exists within the same `DataTemplate` that you are already in?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the Stretch="Uniform"  This should draw a circle that fills the space within your row.